# Browser automatically adding attribute value to tag

Tags: html, angularjs, tags, pug

I have this tag with an attribute without its value

```
<div class='hello' scroll-glue>
```

But when I inspect this element in the browser it adds this value to it as if it is a default value

```
<div class='hello' scroll-glue='scroll-glue'>
```

This creates an issue when using Angular as this directive expects an expression there but if not supplied any expression it uses its default options. But I will never have `scroll-glue` defined as an expression.

For the time being I have edited the directive code itself to check if the attribute value is `scroll-glue` and treat it as if the value has not been specified. But I dont understand why this behaviour is occurring. Is there any flags I need to set in order to disable this *behaviour?

**Browser details :**
Google Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Hey @EduardMalakhov I have updated my answer with the browser details

Comment: I suspect that this might be a third-party script that modifies  the attribute, not chrome itself. With chrome you can try the following to do some additional research:
1. Open developer tools (F12)
2. Select your div in the Elements view
3. Right-click it and set Break on... -> Attribute modifications
4. Reload the page to see which script really does the modification

Comment: I can’t reproduce that, in the exact same Chrome version. When I create a document with a DIV element with the attribute as you have shown, then in DOM inspector I still see it that way - it has not been “expanded” to a name="value" pair. Are you delivering your document as HTML or XML? XML does not allow stand-alone attributes, so it might be that in _that_ case it indeed gets transformed to the result you’re seeing.

Comment: I am actually using JADE as the templating language.

Answer (score 0):

In Jade use `doctype html`. See this [related issue](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/370) on GitHub.